# How to clear the gridview,literal and panel values?

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox called customer id and if the id is not valid, it should display a warning message and needs to go back to the main page where the user retries entering Id again. It works fine if the ID is valid. If the entered Id is invalid, panel and gridview are updating with some random values. How can I clear them? Any suggestions.

```
       DataTable dt = oRecord.GetCustomerName(sId);

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
           // making panel and gridview visible false does not work.
            pnlDetails.visible = false;
            gvInfo.visible= false
            pnlSuccess.Visible = false;
            btnOk.Visible = false;
            txtId.Text = string.Empty;
            txtIdentifier.Focus();

            ViewState["sId"] = string.Empty;              

        }
```

Comment: `GridView1.DataSource = null;`

Comment: I tried this: gvInfo.DataSource = null ; gvInfo.DataBind(); pnldetails.Controls.clear() but it does not work for me. still gridview and panel are updating with random values.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set visible false as it will be setting controls to invisible along with existing data but data is available and bind with these controls in memory. you should clear content of these controls to empty or null.

```
    DataTable dt = oRecord.GetCustomerName(sId);

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        gvInfo.DataSource = null;
        txtId.Text = string.Empty;
        txtIdentifier.Focus();
        ViewState["sId"] = string.Empty;              
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.Tried using .Controls.Clear() which works.